# Layer order of overlapping text and image in Android Listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview, layer

[Updated, as I apparently can't answer my own question yet:   It's as simple as re-ordering the views.  I put the TextView at the end, indicated layout_alignParentLeft="true", and it does the trick.]

I have a typical ListView item description, with text and images (3) in each row.

I noticed that the image (id="@+id/browse_item_row_icon") on the right side of the row was drawn on top of (over) the text.

While not immediately what I wanted, I decided it would actually work, IF I could have that image **behind** the text instead of on top of it.  This would allow me to display more text if necessary, and covering up part of the image will not impact usability.

Is there a way to indicate above/below ordering of views?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >

    <TextView      
        android:id="@+id/browse_item_row_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dip"
      >
    </TextView>

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/browse_item_add_button" 
        android:background="@drawable/ic_add_button" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/browse_item_to_submenu" 
        android:src="@drawable/expander_ic_minimized"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/browse_item_add_button" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/browse_item_row_icon" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_default_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/browse_item_to_submenu" >
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You want to have to have a imageview behind the textview?

Comment: @suri, yes.  And as I indicated in my [update] I was able to accomplish it simply by moving the textview to the end of the layout, and making sure it alignsleft (which was kind of assumed previously when it was at the beginning).

Comment: Well, did you check my answer...?

Comment: @suri, no.  As indicated, I answered my own question, and I didn't want to add a FrameLayout when it was not necessary.  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your case if you want images behind the TextView you can use FrameLayout for that, try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/browse_item_add_button"
                android:background="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
            </ImageButton>

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/browse_item_to_submenu"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/browse_item_add_button">
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/browse_item_row_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/browse_item_to_submenu">
            </ImageView>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/browse_item_row_text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="24dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ">
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

make the texview background transparent, by using

```
android:background="#0000"
```

I think it should do the job.

Comment: In my case, the image was obstructing the text, and I wanted to see the text.  Having it (now) overlay the image provides me space and can still (sort of) see the images.